# ¿Es normal que los tweets obtenidos con tweepy tengan esta forma?

Tags: python, json, twitter-api, tweepy

Estoy obteniendo tweets con tweepy y quiero saber por qué los tweets me salen cortados o incompletos. De esta forma:

> "¿Quién es Piñera y cómo llegó a ser presidente? ¿Por qué cancelar dos cumbres pero reafirmar la sede de la final de… https://t.co/bUuNoWxug3"

Tienen algún largo predeterminado?

Evidentemente no todos me salen de esa forma, sólo los más extensos.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por defecto, tweepy trunca el atributo `text` de los tweets a 140 cáracteres. Cuando eso ocurre, el atributo `truncated` del tweet es `True`. Por ejemplo:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="argentina").items(10):
    print(f"El texto del mensaje es: {tweet.text}")

    if tweet.truncated:
        print("Este tweet ha sido truncado")
```

Para obtener los tweets completos se puede cambiar el parametro `tweet_mode` que por defecto es `compat` (compatible) a `extended` (extendido), en los métodos que devuelvan tweets. En vez de tener un atributo `text`, el tweet pasa a tener un atributo `full_text` y el atributo `truncated` siempre es `False`. Por ejemplo:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="argentina", tweet_mode="extended").items(10):
    print(f"El texto completo del tweet es: {tweet.full_text}")
```

Para más información, podés leer [la documentación de tweepy sobre los *extended tweets*](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/extended_tweets.html) (en inglés)

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvió.